# How to use FBEventManager in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, notifications, firebird, jaybird

I am trying to add a Firebird database insert notification in my web app based on Java Servlets and JSP. I just find that the Jaybird holds an events API but I don't know how to implement those methods.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do? What did you try and what are you stuck on? Your question is far too broad and unclear to answer.

Comment: especially with JSP... Aren't HTTP servers only working when remote WWW browser asks them to? they just do not keep themselves running round-the-clock to be able to receive events

Comment: @Arioch'The You can have asynchronous processing in servlets, although I'd still don't think that would be ideal

Comment: thanks Mark, I want to notify the user of my web app about the insertion of a new row in the database (table Demand), witch is actually a new request. In my database, the table concerned by the notification have a trigger after insert. I don't know how to implement the notification in the JSP of the user.

Comment: Could you explain how to implement that asynchronous processing in the servlet

Comment: You need to use @<username> to notify people. In any case, in my opinion your question is far too broad as you're expecting us to deliver an entire solution to you. I doubt using async processing is the right solution, you'd probably be better off with a different solution, eg using websockets.

Comment: does it mean that I have to rewrite my servlet?